# Is there a way to open a file in split view from recent files popup

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have this `Recent files` popup:

[image]

I can open any file from it by pressing `ENTER`. Is there any way to open the file in a split view? I have `tab limit` set to `1`, so opening a file from `Recent files` and then opening it in a split view replaces the currently open file. I'd like to open a file in a split view without replacing the current tab. Maybe key mapping somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not (as far as my knowledge goes).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108556 -- watch this and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

The only other possible options (generally speaking):

- `Shift + Enter` to open it in a new/detached editor.
- Open as usual and then use `Move Down` or `Move Right` to move it in that split group (will create if you do not have one). But this will NOT work if you set to have only 1 editor tab max.
- Open as usual, clone it to bottom/right side (so it opens in both splitters) and then re-open recently closed file in one of the split areas again *(yeah .. long and inconvenient)*.
- Move focus to another splitter before invoking `Recent Files` (if you have no such splitter yet -- create one for current file). Now chose file as usual -- it will replace file in current splitter *(inconvenient as you need to think about correct location in advance instead of quickly opening the needed file)*.

Comment: thanks, what is `move down` and `right` here `Open as usual and then use Move Down or Move Right`?

Comment: @Maximus Right click on Editor tab and you will see those actions. For them to work  you need to have more than one opened tab. Originally IDE only had `Split Vertically/Horizontally` sort of actions that would clone current file in another splitter. Recently added (well, no more than 2 years  AFAIK) `Move Down/Right` creates (if needed) and moves current file into that splitter without leaving original tab behind.

Comment: got it, thanks, hopefully they will soon implement the functionality in the question